# Adding new items to ListView: Can't modify the content

Tags: android, listview

**EDIT:** I think the post is becoming into a mess with all these edits. I' going to try to explain the problem from the beginning.

I have an activity with a ListView and a button to add new items.
Each item in the listview is compesed by an EditText and two buttons.
The problem is that if I add a new item the texts winthin the EditTexts are restored to their initial values...

I'm adding the new items with:

```
adapter.add(new Contacto(""));
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

"Contacto" is the name of the class I'm using in my arrayList.

@Iftikar Urrhman Khan suggested to me to use the addTextChangedListener but I don't know how.

This is the code of my customadapter:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class ContactsArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contacto>{

    private ArrayList<Contacto> contactos;
    private Activity activity;

    public ContactsArrayAdapter(Activity a, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Contacto> contactos) {
        super(a, textViewResourceId, contactos);
        this.contactos = contactos;
        this.activity = a;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder{
        public EditText mail;
        public Button btn_contactos;
        public Button btn_delete;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        final Contacto item = contactos.get(position);

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi =
                (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.contacto, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.mail = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_to);
            holder.btn_contactos = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_contacts);
            holder.btn_delete = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);            
            v.setTag(holder);

            //Delete;
            holder.btn_delete.setTag(position);
            holder.btn_delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                    int posicion = (Integer)v.getTag();
                    contactos.remove(posicion);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

            //Add contacts
            holder.btn_contactos.setTag(position);
            holder.btn_contactos.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                    //Log.d("TAG", "Botón contactos pulsado, pos: "+Integer.toString(pos));
                    ((Contactos)getContext()).setPosicion((Integer)v.getTag());

                    Intent intent =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI);
                    ((Activity) v.getContext()).startActivityForResult(intent, MainActivity.act_pick_contact_mail);
                }
            });    

            //TextEdit Listener 
            holder.mail.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

                //holder.mail.setText(item.mail);
                //item.mail=arg0.toString();

                //int posi = (Integer)v.getTag();
                //contactos.set(posi, new Contacto(arg0.toString()));

                //contactos.get(pos).setMail(arg0.toString());

            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

            }           
            });

        }
        else holder=(ViewHolder)v.getTag();

        holder.mail.setTag(position);

        if (item != null) {
            holder.mail.setText(item.getMail());
        }

        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to save your textviews values,because notifydatasetchange call get view again for every visible row

Comment: what do you mean with save your textviews? Do I need to update my arrayList with the texts before to do the adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() and restore the texts after that ?

Comment: I've debugged the code and I've seen the content of my arrayList and is not updated with the values of the screen. How can I get the reference to the textviews of each item from my activity to obtain their texts and update the array?

Comment: you have to save your updated values

Comment: can you post your code that will help

Comment: save the updated values where and how? 
Wich code do you want ? the code of my current adapter?

Comment: your custom adapter code

Comment: ok, added in the first post.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your code is when editText values changed its not updated in arraylist `contactos`.

when you add one more item to your array list it has the same older value in it.

you can add `addTextChangedListener` to your edit text

```
holder.mail.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

}
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {


}
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

}});
```

Comment: Ok, I'v created the listener (i've changed tha name of the last method by onTextChanged). I've put a breakpoint in method afterTextChanged and is triggered a lot of times. The problem is that I don't know how to update the arrayList without knowning the index of the item I need to modify. Do you know how to obtain this index from this method? Thanks.

Comment: @Richal you will write this in your adapter and in your adpater you have access to your position

Comment: I've tried with this code: contactos.set(posi, new Contacto(arg0.toString()));
_____ posi is an attribute I'm updating at the beginning of he method getView with the parameter position. ______ But doesn't work fine.

Comment: @Richal can you post your contactos class as you have to update ,but in code you are setting new contacto